# I have produced a parser.js file using PEG.js, however I get an import error when linking to HTML. Help in solving this would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, peg

I have successfully produced a parser.js file using the peg.js online tool. I have linked it to my html file using:

```
    <script src="parser.js"></script>
```

I intended to run `parser.parse(txt)` from my script however I get *ReferenceError: module is not defined* from the first line of parser.js which is `module.exports =`

Having looked at documentation and I think this is connected with having not installed node.js although I'm running my test using REPL which I thought came with node.js installed anyway.

Is there anyway of getting this running by importing js modules and not having to install node.js and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question here if it is of any use to anyone:

I can change the opening line of the parser.js from
`module.exports` to `var  myparser =`.

Hence I can now run `myparser.parse(txt)` successfully. No need for node.js or the imports statement.